# Templates for Farsi letters and spaces in C# model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model

I want to define a pattern for the Persian language letter for the model. In the pattern I found, it recognizes Persian letters correctly, but space is not recognized and error message appears. Help me please :)
The pattern I used:

```
[RegularExpression("^[\u0622\u0627\u0628\u067E\u062A-\u062C\u0686\u062D-\u0632\u0698\u0633-\u063A\u0641\u0642\u06A9\u06AF\u0644-\u0648\u06CC]+$", ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را به درستی وارد کنید")]
```

Comment: `[RegularExpression(@"^[\u0600-\u06FF]+( [\u0600-\u06FF]+)*$", ErrorMessage = "...")]`

Comment: Hello
If I want Persian numbers in the pattern, what will the pattern look like?

Comment: Well, Persian digits `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` have `U+06F0 ... U+06F9` codes so `[\u0600-\u06FF]` will match Persian digits as well.